# I have manufacturedFrom and manufacturedTo columns which hold a year. How to indicate that a car model hasn't stopped being manufactured?

Tags: mysql, database

My `models` database table contains records of car models and looks like this:

```
Table: Models
Columns: id, name, manufacturedFrom, manufacturedTo
```

Which I thought would work great until I realized a model might still be manufactured years after the insertion of the record. So lets say I insert this:

```
Audi Q7, 2005, 2020
```

but then the `Audi Q7` model might still be manufactured for years, so if I create my database table like this, the user of the application would have to update the `manufacturedTo` year every new year, which seems less than perfect to me.

Right now `manufacturedFrom` and `manufacturedTo` can't be null, but maybe I should allow `manufacturedTo` to be null, and also have a boolean column `stillManufactured`. This way the user of the application would still have to edit a couple of models every year when they stop being manufactured, but at least he won't have to change the year of all other models.

This is my idea, but I'd love to hear if anyone has other good suggestions.

Comment: I'd go for the `NULL` option in the `manufacturedTo` field, but then do without a separate field to indicate whether it remains in production.   That can be determined from the other two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manufacturedTo should remain NULL till it s not longer manúfactured, so you have to change the row only once.

And your SELECT query will look like this

```
SELECT 
    name
    ,manufacturedFrom
    , IF(manufacturedTo IS NULL,YEAR(CURDATE()),manufacturedTo) 
FROM Models
WHERE name LIKE 'Audi'
```

Comment: also maybe useful: `SELECT manufacturedFrom <= CURDATE() AND (manufacturedTo IS NULL OR CURDATE() <= manufacturedTo) AS inProduction`.